# how to put html code in php with echo when I alerady use ' and " in my html code

Tags: php, html

```
else
{
    echo <button onclick="window.location.href='des2.php';">lancer les des</button>;    
}
```

How should I mark out the html code ?

Comment: You need to escape one of the sets of quote marks within the string. This is already explained in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I added what I think is a better duplicate question, hopefully this provides some better ideas for you. Escaping quote marks is the worst of all methods because it's easy to make mistakes.